# GA Enhanced eCommerce not recording transactions

Tags: google-analytics

I am having difficulties getting GA Enhanced eCommerce to work. It is recording the events but no transactions or product data.

I have enabled Enhanced eCommerce in my View settings. I have also used the GA debugger which doesn't seem to show errors.

Here's my code:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-20148609-3', { userId: 'fdea0a15-bf1e-49e0-97c2-8092255aad21' });  
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'title': 'Receipt'
});
ga('send', 'event', 'Completed Order', '');
ga('require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addProduct', { 
  'id': '207033767504',
  'name': "Some product",
  'category': '',
  'brand': '', 
  'variant': '', 
  'price': '29.95', 
  'quantity': 1  
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {   
  'id': '735441434', 
  'affiliation': 'My Store',
  'revenue': '61.15',  
  'tax': '0',  
  'shipping': '31.2',
  //'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'  
});
```

GA Debugger log: https://gist.github.com/cyberwombat/a047eb9077c1c94b374e

Answer (score 3):

Ok fixed. It appears that the pageview call must occur after. I didn't see that in the docs but it seemed to have done the trick.